# How to use linear gradient of CSS to create angle like design

Tags: html, css

I want a design like this on my `<div>`

[image]

But not getting this structure.

My CSS code is :

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #406884 22%,#3b5261 50%, #38464f 80%);
```

Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create 2 gradients, one with a step for the diagonal part and another with a transparent part for the horizontal part

```css
.test {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, black 40%, transparent 40%), 
    linear-gradient(-35deg, black 50%, tomato 50%, tomato 60%, lightgreen 60%, lightgreen 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can generate any type of gradient from below link
http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/